# StringTokenizer delimit once

Tags: java, split, stringtokenizer

I want to split a string (line) by the first whitespace, but only the first.

```
StringTokenizer linesplit = new StringTokenizer(line," ");
```

Take for example "This is a test". Then I want the strings to be "This" and "is a test". How could I use StringTokenizer or is there a better option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
String firstPart = line.substring(0, line.indexOf(" "));
String secondPart = line.substring(line.indexOf(" ")+1);
```

Check docs:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Answer (score 5):

String.split(pattern,resultlength) does it.
use:

```
String[] splitted = line.split(" ",2);
```

the ',2' parameter means that the resulting Array maximum size is 2.

Comment: +1 Very nice solution. I didn't realise `split` had that capability.

Comment: Will it return "This" and "is a test" or "This" and "is" ?

Comment: @Fazovsky "This" and "is a test"

Answer (score 2):

you can use split

```
String[] a = s.split("(?<=^\\S+)\\s");
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to right your own logic for this. Something like this :

```
String[] linesplit = line.split(" ");
String firstString = linesplit[0];
String secondString = new String();
for(for int i=1; i< linesplit.length; i++)
{
    if(i==1)
    {
        secondString =  linesplit[i];
    }
    else if(i != linesplit.length-1)
    {
        secondString = seconString + " " + linesplit[i];
    }
    else
    {
        secondString = seconString + linesplit[i] + " ";
    }
}
```